# Service layer for Languages drop down

Tags: spring, rest, service

I have a languages table and a corresponding model for it in Spring.
*I need to populate a drop down containing the list of languages on different web pages*.
A user can speak one or more languages, same with customer and so on. I have a userService, customerService etc.
Since it is recommended that the controller interact with the service and not DAO directly, should I create a service for languages? The only method in this service would be getLanguages() and that will retrieve the list of languages using DAO and return it back. The controller API method will return this list back to the client so that it can populate the languages drop down.

Thanks

Note: I have created a service for languages. Since I only have about 6 months of experience with Spring, I want to ensure that I'm doing things the right way.